# I always get Sorry username and password are incorrect when i press login (java web application)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I'm learning to build a web application using jsp and servlets.
My web application contains two text fields : one for the username and the seconde for password and a simple button to login.
I'm using an internal database to store the username and the passwords.
But when i press login i get always `sorry username and password are incorrect`

You can find here the code :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class LoginDao {

public static boolean validate(String username, String password) {          
    boolean status = false;  
    Connection conn = null;  
    PreparedStatement pst = null;  
    ResultSet rs = null;  

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";  
    String dbName = "info";  
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    String dBuserName = "root";  
    String dBpasssword = "azerty";
    try {
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();            
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, dBuserName,dBpasssword);
           pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from users where username=? and password=?");
           pst.setString(1, dBusername);
           pst.setString(2, dBpassword);
           rs = pst.executeQuery();
           status = rs.next();}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    } 
    finally {  
        if (conn != null) {  
            try {  conn.close();  }

             catch (SQLException e) {  } } 


        if (pst != null) {   try { pst.close();  } catch (SQLException e) {  }   }  
        if (rs != null) {   try {  
                rs.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) 
           {  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    return status;  
    }
    }
```

LoginServlet.java :

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LoginServlet"})
     public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
        throws ServletException  , IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");    
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

    String n=request.getParameter("username");    
    String p=request.getParameter("password");   

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);  
    if(session!=null)  
    session.setAttribute("name", n);  

    if(LoginDao.validate(n,p)){    
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");    
        rd.forward(request,response);    
    }    
    else{    
        out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");    
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");    
        rd.include(request,response);    
    }    

    out.close();    
}    
}
```

weclome.jsp :

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
  <html>  
   <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
  <title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title>  
     </head>  
     <body>  
     <h3>Welcome </h3>  
        <h4>  
          Hello,  
    <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></h4>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

my web.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
  <web-app  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
 version="2.5">  
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
     <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>loginDao</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>/LoginDao</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  

      <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>  
      </servlet-mapping>  

    <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  
      </web-app>
```

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Please, do yourself a favor and rename the database credentials into something like dbUsername and dbPassword. Try to use a debugger to see if the statement is realy executed correctly.

Comment: Have you checked that you are getting values of `username` and `password` from request.

Comment: When i debug the LoginServlet.java it returns this message : "The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource."

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
           pst.setString(1, dBusername);
           pst.setString(2, dBpassword);
```

to

```
           pst.setString(1, username);
           pst.setString(2, password);
```

If you are using an IDE and you should debug such issues. If not using IDE then please use them as they help aid development like Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.

I understand you are writing quick code to make it work. I am sure you will improve the code.

You should extract out the DB connection steps from your DAO so that you can use the same in multiple DAOs instead of repeating the code. Also inject the DB properties from outside instead of coding.

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm just a beginner in web-application coding. I hava to improve my skills. There's a lot of work to do.